# Confusion about different definitions of LK, LJ, NK, and NJ

Tags: proof-theory

I try to understand the differences between the calculi mentioned above, mainly the difference between natural deduction and the sequence calculus. For this I consulted the [wikipedia article on the sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus), "Proof Theory" by Gaisi Takeuti and "Basic Proof Theory" by Troelstra and Schwichtenberg.

The wikipedia article says that natural deduction (which I understand to be **NK**) has judgements of the form $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n\vdash B$ and then goes on to define the sequent calculus (which I understand to be **LK**) as a generalisation of judgements to $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n\vdash B_1, B_2, ..., B_k$.

Takeuti, as well as Troelstra and Schwichtenberg, define **LK** (resp. **G1c**) with judgements of the form $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n\vdash B_1, B_2, ..., B_k$ and then say that we define **LJ** (resp. **G1i**) by restricting the judgements to have only one formula on the right side of the turnstile.

So my question is essentially: if I restrict judgements of **LK** to have only one formula on the right side of the turnstile, do I get **LJ** or **NK**?

Comment: The difference is in the rules: natural deduction has introduction and elimination rules on the right-hand side, whereas a sequent calculus has only introduction rules, but on both sides.

Comment: You get $\mathbf{LJ}$.  $\mathbf{NK}$ and $\mathbf{LJ}$ have the same shape of sequents, but, as Emil Jeřábek says, they manipulate such sequents in rather different ways.